# How do I make quiz display student answers and show correct answers with grade?

Tags: python, arrays, loops

So I am basically trying to replicate this image as shown. The problem I have is that whenever I run the program it basically tells me I can't run it. I'm not sure if I have some placing wrong somewhere in my code. I get an error whenever I run it due to a syntax error at the "else:" part. [image]

```
def main():
examAnswers = ['A', 'C', 'A', 'A', 'D', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'C', 'B']
countCorrect = 0
countWrong = 0
studentAnswers = getStudentAnswers()

for i in range(10):
 if examAnswers[i] == studentAnswers[i]:
    print("Congratulations!", countCorrect + 1)
    else:
        print("Wrong!", countWrong + 1)


listOfAnswers = []
for qnum in range(10):
print("Enter answer to question ", qnum+1, ":", sep="", end="")
listofAnswers.append(input())
return listOfAnswers

main()
```

Comment: what is `main()`? also some of your indentation is wrong....

Comment: We need the full error and traceback

Comment: We also need the code for getstudentanswers

Comment: @Netwave Sorry its supposed to be def main():

Comment: @MosesMartinez you can edit your question - can you please do so to add the necessary pieces of information requested in the other comments?

Comment: Why don't you try reducing the scope of the problem and asking a question once you have a minimal reproducible issue.

Comment: How do I get the full error and traceback? I'm sorry I am new to all of this.

Comment: Is there an error that you are receiving? If yes, can you add that to the question so we can try to understand what might be wrong. It might be good to fix the indentation in your example since that will help us understand your code better. Finally, have you called the `main()` function at all?

Comment: okay I edit it my script but every time I run it, it says there is an error syntax at the "else:" part. and I added main() at the end of the script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To begin with, I would say keep learning Python and going through tutorials to improve.
I will explain the refactored code I have written as better as possible in the comments in the code, so you can get an idea of what is going on here. If you still have doubts, feel free to ask me in the comments.

The `getStudentAnswers` logic is defined in a function as below, and I call that function in the main piece of code, which starts from `examAnswers` variable. Indentation plays a big role in python, so the code which is not indented is run first, and it calls the `getStudentAnswers` function.

```py
#Function to get the answers of students
def getStudentAnswers():

    listOfAnswers = []

    #Run a for loop 10 times
    for qNum in range(10):

        #Get the answer from the user
        print("Enter answer to question ", qNum + 1, ": ", sep="", end="")
        answer = input()

        #Append the answer to the list
        listOfAnswers.append(answer)

    #Return the final list of answers
    return listOfAnswers

#List of valid exam answers
examAnswers = ['A', 'C', 'A', 'A', 'D', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'C', 'B']

#Variable to hold the count of correct and wrong answers
countCorrect = 0
countWrong = 0

#Get all the answers from the students
studentAnswers = getStudentAnswers()

#Run a for loop 10 times
for i in range(10):

    #If exam answer matches student answer, print it and increment countCorrect
    if examAnswers[i] == studentAnswers[i]:
        countCorrect+=1
        print('Question',i+1,'is correct!')

    # If exam answer does not match student answer, print it and increment countWrong
    else:
        print('Question',i+1,'is WRONG!')
        countWrong+=1

#Calculate number of missedQuestions and grade and print it
missedQuestions = 10 - countCorrect
grade = 10*countCorrect

print('You missed',missedQuestions,'questions.')
print('You grade is:',grade)
```

Once you the run the code, you should get the required output as below.

```
Enter answer to question 1: A
Enter answer to question 2: B
Enter answer to question 3: C
Enter answer to question 4: D
Enter answer to question 5: A
Enter answer to question 6: B
Enter answer to question 7: C
Enter answer to question 8: D
Enter answer to question 9: A
Enter answer to question 10: A
Question 1 is correct!
Question 2 is WRONG!
Question 3 is WRONG!
Question 4 is WRONG!
Question 5 is WRONG!
Question 6 is correct!
Question 7 is correct!
Question 8 is WRONG!
Question 9 is WRONG!
Question 10 is WRONG!
You missed 7 questions.
You grade is: 30
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This means so much I was stuck over this thing for about 2 days!

Comment: No issues! Python is meant to be  easy, just keep pushing hard :)